# Was ist zu verstehen unter einer "Vollziehung der Ehe in der Marienkapelle der Hofburg"?

Tags: word-usage, etymology

Dieser Satz stammt aus [Alfred Kohlers](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Kohler_%28Historiker%29) *["Ferdinand I.](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdinand_I._%28HRR%29), 1503–1564. Fürst, König und Kaiser"*:

> Nachdem dann am 12. Juli zu Füssen der Kaiser seinen Heiratsvertrag
>   mit Anna für null und nichtig erklärt hatte, erfolgte am 20. Juli zu
>   Wien in der Marienkapelle der Hofburg die feierliche Vollziehung der
>   Ehe.

[Quelle](https://books.google.de/books?id=1cVR2wbob0AC&pg=PA89&hl=de&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=snippet&q=heiratsvertrag&f=false)

Was könnte der Autor hier genau mit *Vollziehung* meinen? Wenn ich als heutiger Leser von der *Vollziehung der Ehe* in der *Marienkapelle der Hofburg* höre, gibt das Anlass zum Schmunzeln, denn ich interpretiere *Vollziehung* hier als ersten Geschlechtsverkehr.

Hat sich hierzu der Sprachgebrauch hierzu seit dem 16. Jahrhundert so stark geändert (was ich vermute), oder waren es die moralischen Sitten (was ich für unwahrscheinlich halte), oder lese ich selbst das Wort im Kontext falsch? Oder gibt es schließlich gar einen Unterschied zwischen *Vollziehung* und *[Vollzug](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vollzug_der_Ehe)* zu beachten?

Comment: Willkommen auf dem Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache! Pro forma weise ich dich auf [tour] und [help] hin, aber anhand deiner Reputation anderswo schätze ich, dass du dich gut auskennst ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die Verwirrung stammt wohl hauptsächlich aus der Annahme

> Wenn ich als *heutiger Leser* von der Vollziehung der Ehe in der Marienkapelle der Hofburg höre, gibt das Anlass zum Schmunzeln,

Das erste Zitat stammt aus einer modernen Biografie, die 2003 erschien.

Zu den tatsächlichen Abläufen um die Ehe zwischen Ferdinand und Anna ist historisches Wissen hilfreich:

> Bei der Wiener Doppelhochzeit 1515 heiratete der 56-jährige Kaiser Maximilian I. stellvertretend für einen seiner Enkel die 12-jährige Anna von Ungarn und Böhmen. Sollte kein Ehevertrag mit einem seiner Enkel zustande kommen, würde er Anna selbst zur Frau nehmen. Dazu kam es nicht, weil Maximilian 1519 in Wels starb. Maximilians Enkel, Kaiser Karl V., fixierte jedoch am 7. November 1520 in Köln einen Ehevertrag zwischen seinem Bruder, dem späteren Kaiser Ferdinand I., und Anna. Der Ehevertrag wurde am 11. Dezember 1520 in Innsbruck bestätigt, wo sich Anna in der Zeit vor ihrer Hochzeit gemeinsam mit ihrer Schwägerin Maria aufhielt.
>
> Die Hochzeit fand am 26. Mai 1521 in Linz statt. Der Salzburger Fürsterzbischof Matthäus Lang von Wellenburg traute die 17-jährige Anna und den 18-jährigen Ferdinand in Anwesenheit vieler hochrangiger Kleriker (Bischof und späterer Kardinal Bernhard von Cles von Trient, Bischof Christophorus Rauber von Laibach, Bischof Berthold Pürstinger von Chiemsee, Bischof Georg von Slatkonia von Wien, Probst Girolamo Balbi von Bratislava) und vieler namhafter weltlicher Führungspersonen (Herzog Wilhelm von Bayern, Herzog Ernst von Bayern, Markgraf Kasimir von Brandenburg, Markgraf Johann von Brandenburg, die Grafen von Gradisca, Siegmund von Herberstein). **Die Trauung fand *wahrscheinlich* in der Linzer Stadtpfarrkirche statt,** wo das Herz von Kaiser Friedrich III. ruht. Die Hochzeit wurde weniger aufwändig als die prunkvolle Wiener Hochzeit im Jahr 1515 gefeiert, es wurden jedoch ein Turnier und einige Waffenspiele abgehalten.
> <sub>[–– WP: Linzer Hochzeit](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linzer_Hochzeit)</sub>

Die Geschichte wurde schliesslich geradezu vorbildhaft für komplizierteste Liebesverirrungen in Groschenromanen, da sowohl die ungarischen Stände Einwände bezüglich der standesgemäßen Verheiratung Annas äußerten (in deren Sicht hatte Ferdinand wohl [*ideas above his station*](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/53885)), als auch Anna selbst zu Erkennen gab, dass sie nicht Ferdinand sondern dessen Bruder Karl bevorzugte.

Ergänzend zu den im Wikipediaeintrag bereits genannten Stufen der Eheschliessung ist noch zu ergänzen:

> Auf der Heimreise von der Krönung Karls V. in Aachen unterzeichneten die Gesandten, der Gespan von Zala, Ambros Sárkány von Ákosháza, und der Geheimrat und Propst von Pressburg/Pozsony/Bratislava Hieronymus Balbus, am 7. November 1520 einen Vertrag mit Karl in diesem Sinne, und in ihrem Beisein **kam es am 11. Dezember in Innsbruck zum Ringtausch zwischen Anna und (*dem abwesenden) Ferdinand,* wie auch zur symbolischen Eheschließung.** Ludwig entsandte Stefan Werbıczi und Hieronymus Balbus als Gesandte10 nach Worms, wo sie mit dem V orsatz, die Verhandlungen fortzusetzen und die bisherigen Vereinbarungen abzustimmen, am 20. April den neuerlichen auf Anna und Ferdinand bezogenen Heiratsvertrag unterzeichneten; Ort und Zeitpunkt der Hochzeit wurden fixiert:
> zu Pfingsten 1521 in Linz. Danach ernannte der ungarische König Markgraf Georg von Brandenburg, Ambros Sárkány von Ákosháza und Hieronymus Balbus zu Gesandten, die mit einer Vollmacht ausgestattet waren, welche ihnen volle Handlungsfreiheit für die Verhandlungen mit Erzherzog Ferdinand in Linz gewährte. In der Anweisung hieß es, sie sollten – was auch immer die vorherigen Gesandten bzw. Beauftragten 1520 in Köln und später 1521 in Worms in Bezug auf die Ehe seiner Schwester Anna vereinbart hätten –, die Verhandlungen fortsetzen bzw. zu Ende führen; ebenso sollten sie sich in den Bedingungen die Aussteuer betreffend einigen, ferner in all dem, was Sicherheit, Frieden und Gedeihen der beiden Länder beträfe. All das war nötig geworden, weil Karl den Erbteil Ferdinands noch fast zwei Jahre lang, bis zu den im Januar und Februar 1522 in Brüssel unterzeichneten Verträgen bald enger, bald großzügiger festzulegen bestrebt war.
> <sub>–– Zoltán Csepregi: "„... ich will kain fleis nit sparen...“ – Königin Maria von Ungarn und das Haus Brandenburg", in: Martina Fuchs & Orsolya Réthelyi (Hg.): "Maria von Ungarn (1505–1558) – Eine Renaissancefürstin",  *Geschichte in der Epoche Karls V.,* Bd. 8., Münster 2007. p59-72.</sub>

Es bleibt daher festzuhalten, dass erstens nicht wirklich feststeht, wo genau denn nun einerseits nach üblichem Sprachgebrauch tatsächlich die "Ehe geschlossen" oder die "Ehe vollzogen" wurde. Andererseits is zweitens zu vermuten, dass der Autor des Eingangszitates zwar die tatsächliche *Eheschliessung* nach gängiger Vorstellung – beide Eheleute stehen sich persönlich gegenüber, geben Ja-wort und tauschen Ringe – erst in der genannten Ortschaft als *"vollzogen"* anzusehen beschreibt.  Der geschlechtliche Vollzug – *consummatio* – der wird dann wohl tatsächlich am selben Ort, nämlich aller Wahrscheinlichkeit nach in der Burg zu der die Kapelle gehört, stattgefunden haben. Angesichts der genannten Details scheint es sich lediglich um eine sprachliche Ungenauigkeit des modernen Autors zu handeln: Nach langem Hüh und Hott, wurde eine bereits mehrfach *beschlossene* Ehe – vertraglich, unter anderem auch zwischen ganz anderen Parteien als den Eheleuten, ferner symbolisch, auch *geschlossen*. Den sexuellen Aspekt darunter ebenfalls zu verstehen scheint fast zulässig, ([es ergibt sich dann halt so](http://www.habsburger.net/de/kapitel/ferdinand-i-ehe-und-nachkommen)), nicht jedoch bezüglich der überpräzisen Ortsangabe "in einer Kirche".

Answer (score 12):

Vollziehung und Vollzug sind hier Synonyme für die kirchenrechtliche *Consummatio*, das heißt den ersten Geschlechtsverkehr nach geschlossener Ehe. Daran waren wichtige Rechtsfolgen geknüpft, wie zB die prinzipielle Unauflösbarkeit. Eine *matrimonium ratum sed non consummatum* (geschlossene, aber nicht vollzogene Ehe) war demgegenüber vergleichsweise leicht lösbar. Sie wurde bisweilen auch zwischen Kindern, durch Stellvertreter usw geschlossen.

Wegen der rechtlichen Bedeutung des Vorgangs erfolgte dieser Vollzug der Ehe, gerade bei staatspolitisch wichtigen Ehen, bisweilen durchaus vor Zeugen.

Answer (score 9):

Zu unterscheiden sind zwei wichtige Begriffe:

- **Die Trauung, die Hochzeit**
  Das ist ein kurzer, nur wenige Minuten dauernder, zeremonieller Akt. Eine gesellschaftlich anerkannte Institution (Staat oder Kirche) ermächtig eine eigens dafür ausgebildete Person (Standesbeamter, Priester), diese Zeremonie vor Zeugen zu vollziehen.
- **Die Ehe**
  Das ist ein lange andauernder Pakt zwischen zwei Personen. Die Gültigkeit dieses Paktes beginnt im Moment der Trauung und endet mit der Scheidung oder mit dem Tod eines der beiden Partner.

Da eine Ehe in fast allen Kulturen geschlossen wurde, um eine Familie zu gründen, also um Kinder zu bekommen und großzuziehen, galt eine Ehe oft erst nach dem ersten ersten Geschlechtsakt als endgültig geschlossen. Das hatte rechtliche Folgen, denn eine vollzogene Ehe (also eine Ehe, in der bereits Geschlechtsverkehr stattgefunden hat) trug in sich bereits die Möglichkeit, eine Familie mit Nachwuchs zu sein. Daher konnte eine vollzogene Ehe entweder gar nicht mehr, oder nur mit erheblichen Winkelzügen geschieden werden, während das bei einer nicht vollzogenen Ehe etwas leichter war. Nicht vollzogene Ehen können ach geltendem Kirchenrecht geschieden werden, während das für vollzogene Ehen z.B. nach dem Recht der röm. kath. Kirche auch im 21. Jahrhundert nicht möglich ist.

Dahinter stand auch der Gedanke, dass Sexualität nur innerhalb einer Ehe stattfinden darf, und dass man dem einmal gewählten Partner ein Leben lang treu sein muss.

Aus diesem Grund fand der Vollzug der Ehe (also der Geschlechtsverkehr) in einigen Fällen (am Hof einiger europäischer Königshäuser) durchaus auch vor Zeugen statt, die die Durchführung des Geschlechtsverkehrs amtlich beurkundeten.

Jedoch ging ich bisher immer davon aus, dass dieser Vollzug in den Schlafgemächern des Paares stattfand. Dass man das an einem geweihten Ort gemacht hätte, erscheint mir doch etwas unglaubwürdig. Daher gehe ich trotz der im zitierten Dokument gewählten Wortwahl »Vollzug der Ehe« davon aus, dann in Wahrheit der »Vollzug der Trauung« gemeint war.